# Using words for "like" query on each word

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I've got this query which works correctly in looping through a set of words and doing a like condition on certain fields for each word, along with searching on DOB if required.

Can anyone see a way of doing this within the need for the While loop? I can't see to find a way of using STRING_SPLIT to do this which I've tried but I can't add a LIKE using this.

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

--what will become stored proc parameters
DECLARE @searchwords NVARCHAR(max) = 'mary jo' --can accept many search words
DECLARE @LowerDate date = '01 Jan 1980' --could be NULL
DECLARE @UpperDate date = '31 Dec 1980' --could be NULL
--local variables
DECLARE @word NVARCHAR(50)
Declare @ID int

Create Table #SearchWords
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Word varchar(50)
)

Create Table #Results
(
    ClientID int,
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    VerificationCode varchar(100),
    DOB date
)

Insert into #SearchWords
(
    Word
)
SELECT 
    value 
FROM 
    STRING_SPLIT(@searchwords, ' ')  
WHERE 
    RTRIM(value) <> ''  

While (Select Count(*) From #SearchWords) > 0
Begin

    Select Top 1 
        @ID = ID,
        @Word = Word
    From 
        #SearchWords

    INSERT INTO #Results
    (
        ClientID,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        VerificationCode,
        DOB
    )
    SELECT
        ClientID,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        VerificationCode,
        DOB
    FROM
        Client
    WHERE
       (FirstName like '%' + @Word + '%' or
        LastName like '%' + @Word + '%' or
        VerificationCode like '%' + @Word + '%')

    Delete #SearchWords Where ID = @ID
End

IF (@LowerDate IS NOT NULL and @UpperDate IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Results
    (
        ClientID,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        VerificationCode,
        DOB
    )
    SELECT
        ClientID,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        VerificationCode,
        DOB
    FROM
        Client
    WHERE
       (DOB >= @LowerDate and DOB <= @UpperDate)
END

select * from #Results

drop table #Results
drop table #SearchWords
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following query

```
SELECT
    ClientID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    VerificationCode,
    DOB
FROM Client c
WHERE EXISTS(
          SELECT *
          FROM #SearchWords s
          WHERE (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
             OR (c.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
             OR (c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
        )
  AND DOB BETWEEN ISNULL(@LowerDate,DOB) AND ISNULL(@UpperDate,DOB)
```

A variant for a question from your comment

```
SELECT
    ClientID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    VerificationCode,
    DOB
INTO #Result
FROM Client c
WHERE EXISTS(
          SELECT *
          FROM #SearchWords s
          WHERE (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
             OR (c.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
             OR (c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
        )
  AND DOB BETWEEN ISNULL(@LowerDate,DOB) AND ISNULL(@UpperDate,DOB)

IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #Result))
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  FROM #Result
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT
      ClientID,
      FirstName,
      LastName,
      VerificationCode,
      DOB
  FROM Client
  WHERE DOB BETWEEN ISNULL(@LowerDate,DOB) AND ISNULL(@UpperDate,DOB)
END

DROP TABLE #Result
```

A variant without a temporary table

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
  ClientID,
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  VerificationCode,
  DOB
FROM
  (
    SELECT
        1 RowPriority,
        ClientID,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        VerificationCode,
        DOB
    FROM Client c
    WHERE EXISTS(
              SELECT *
              FROM #SearchWords s
              WHERE (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
                 OR (c.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
                 OR (c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
            )
      AND DOB BETWEEN ISNULL(@LowerDate,DOB) AND ISNULL(@UpperDate,DOB)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        2 RowPriority,
        ClientID,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        VerificationCode,
        DOB
    FROM Client c
    WHERE DOB BETWEEN ISNULL(@LowerDate,DOB) AND ISNULL(@UpperDate,DOB)
  ) q
ORDER BY RowPriority
```

One more variant

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
  ClientID,
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  VerificationCode,
  DOB
FROM
  (
    -- the first scenario - we use only words filter without the DOB filter
    SELECT
        1 RowPriority, -- max priority
        ClientID,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        VerificationCode,
        DOB
    FROM Client c
    WHERE EXISTS(
              SELECT *
              FROM #SearchWords s
              WHERE (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
                 OR (c.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
                 OR (c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
            )
      AND @LowerDate IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    -- the second scenario - we use words and DOB filters
    SELECT
        2 RowPriority,
        ClientID,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        VerificationCode,
        DOB
    FROM Client c
    WHERE EXISTS(
              SELECT *
              FROM #SearchWords s
              WHERE (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
                 OR (c.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
                 OR (c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
            )
      AND DOB BETWEEN @LowerDate AND @UpperDate

    -- the third scenario - we use only DOB filter
    SELECT
        3 RowPriority, -- min priority
        ClientID,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        VerificationCode,
        DOB
    FROM Client c
    WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #SearchWords)=0
      AND DOB BETWEEN @LowerDate AND @UpperDate
  ) q
ORDER BY RowPriority
```

A variant with an auxiliary variable

```
-- an auxiliary variable
DECLARE @Scenario int=CASE
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #SearchWords)>0 THEN IIF(@LowerDate IS NULL,1,2)
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #SearchWords)=0 AND @LowerDate IS NOT NULL THEN 3
    END

SELECT
    ClientID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    VerificationCode,
    DOB
FROM Client c
WHERE
    (
        (
            @Scenario IN(1,2)
            AND EXISTS(
                  SELECT *
                  FROM #SearchWords s
                  WHERE (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
                     OR (c.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
                     OR (c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
                )
        )
        OR
        @Scenario=3 -- this scenario doesn't use word filter
    )
  AND
    (
        (@Scenario IN(2,3) AND DOB BETWEEN @LowerDate AND @UpperDate)
        OR
        @Scenario=1 -- this scenario doesn't use DOB filter
    )
```

Comment: My bad @Leran2002, is there an easy way if words are not passed but LowerDate and UpperDate are that it will show a result?

Comment: @James - I changed my answer. As variant you can use a temporary table.

Comment: @James - I added one more variant. Here doesn't use a temporary table. I think the second variant is better.

Comment: that WITH TIES option is very interesting. Without it the result is incorrect, so it's obviously key to the query results. Do you mind explaining why?

Comment: See the picture - https://hsto.org/files/2ec/af9/cb3/2ecaf9cb3b07405f82fe8ed43a2a5a71.png

Comment: Thanks, I get that there, but how does that Salary relate to this question because there isn't that kind of field?

Comment: WITH TIES depends from values in ORDER BY. If result has only RowPriority=2 then TOP 1 returns  the first row with RowPriority=2. After that WITH TIES returns all the rows where RowPriority=2, too.

Comment: In my picture TOP 3 returns 3 rows which contains Salary=(1500, 2000). If you add WITH TIES then into the result will be included all rows where Salary=(1500, 2000), too.

Comment: Just realised it doesn't actually work @Leran2002 , if you pass a search word that doesn't exist it returns all records from the Client table.  If you pass a word that does exist however it does work. Any ideas?

Comment: @James - I think I misunderstood you. Try to check one more variant. I added it in the end of the answer.

Comment: thanks, it's not if we don't have any words. It's that if there are no results. For Example if the search word is "James", and there are no James it returns all the records in the Client table because I think it then uses DateOfBirth? It's 3 scenarios:

1) Pass a word or words 
2) Pass a word or words and a @LowerDate/@UpperDate
3) Pass only @LowerDate/@UpperDate

Comment: With your modified code above, if I only pass "James" and there are no James in the database, it returns all the rows from the client table. This seems to be the result of the UNION.

Comment: Maybe, do you need to add one more parameter for select a scenario? Then you can use the following "WHERE (@ScenarioID=1 AND ...) OR (@ScenarioID=2 AND ... AND ...) OR (@ScenarioID=3 AND ...)". You can add combobox for select a necessary scenario and enable/disable parameter fields (or show/hide them) on your form for selected scenario.

Comment: @James - As variant I added one more query for three scenario. I used there three subqueries. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the last subquery. Change into `WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #SearchWords)=0
          AND DOB BETWEEN @LowerDate AND @UpperDate`.

Comment: @James - You are welcome! I invented another variant with an auxiliary variable. I think it's more shorter and clearly. See my updated answer.